# Weird reflection in glossy material when camera is in front of the object

Tags: camera, reflection

I noticed this problem also through glass.
When my camera is looking in front of the object, I see a dark circle in the reflection. It only happen with metal or glass material.

I think it comes from the camera, as if it was the camera shadow.

I tried to render without the camera visible, does not change anything.

Does someone encountered this problem before or is it still the beta ? I use 2.8

Thx
[image]
[image: Weird dark spot]

Comment: Could it just  be the shadow of the object, that is attached to the string? Try to change the direction of your lightsource.

Comment: Is it possible you could [upload your .blend](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/658/599)?